# IBM Marketing Cloud Push Notification Cordova plugin not working

Tags: android, cordova

I am pulling my hair here with this IBM Cloud push notifications and unfortunately I am getting nowhere.
The documentation is not very good and the information that is there is ambiguous.
I will summarize my issues below:

First things first,

1. [Link to download Cordova plugin](https://developer.ibm.com/push/docs/ibm-mobile-push-notification-applications-3-x/sdks/download-ibm-push-notfication-plugin-for-cordova-3-x/)
2. [Link to documentation](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSMRK7_3.0.0/AppPush/Integrations/intro_apachecordova.html)

All the management bit is done (create database, register app, register Google Message Service etc).  So next step is to create the app itself. I´ve tried to follow the tutorial, but there are a lot of “Unknowns”

[image]

1. What format should I add the custom actions? Comma separated? Space separated? ???
2. What file? There are at least 3 build property files. Where those dependencies come from ? Need to download them?
3. Where ? On my computer or in the project somewhere?
4. “and the config.xml file is filled out” Filled out with what????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Custom actions are space-separated.

It's best to start with the sample app and expand from there. Those instructions are at least a little clearer:

https://developer.ibm.com/customer-engagement/docs/watson-marketing/ibm-engage-2/mobile-push/mobile-push-cordova/customizing-and-testing-the-sample-cordova-app/

You will have to edit config.xml to specify your iOS bundle ID and version number.